# Why are batteries used with garage and gate motors in South Africa?

Tags: batteries, motor, mains-supply

In South Africa (230V, 50Hz) as far as I know, most gate and garage motors are connected to a motor controller and powered by usually 12V lead acid batteries, which are then connected to a charge controller to the mains. Why are the lead acid batteries necessary? Why can't the gate or garage motors be powered from the mains instead of the lead acid batteries? Has it got something to do with current spikes when first starting the motor?

Comment: They can be powered from the mains, and usually are, at least in Europe. Maybe mains power is unreliable in SA and people want access to car and road when mains power is down?

Comment: The obvious answer is power cuts. You don't want to be locked out of your home.

Comment: In passing, things like clock radios usually have battery backup (for the clock) in some countries but not others.  In the 1990s, for example, French clock radios always had a battery, British ones did not.  Toasters in France suited long, narrow, thick slices; british toasters were for thin squarish slices; because of the most common styles of bread.  It's the often-overlooked cultural requirements of product design.

Comment: It’s a built in UPS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Appears to be directly due to the unreliability of the power. From a [South African supplier website](https://www.championgatemotors.co.za/gate-motor-prices/) (emphasis added):

> How to choose the best gate motor for your gate
>
> The best motor gate is firstly the one that will last you longer.
> Secondly the motor must be able provide security and convenience you
> require like gate opening speed. Thirdly the gate motor must be able
> to run your gate with no much effort and strain. **Finally the motor
> must have battery back up in case of power failures or load shedding.**

Indirectly, the security environment in many areas of South Africa is such that one might not want to exit your vehicle to manually open a gate in the event of a power failure.